# Python/Pandas - importing CSV getting weird errors

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've got a csv and its lines look like this:

```
CNPJ                Razao social                Nome fantasia      Endereco Cidade  Estado  Telefone    Email   Natureza juridica   Atividade primaria  Atividades secundarias  Data de fundacao    Situacao cadastral  Socios e administradores    Capital Social
02.787.185/0001-51  PEREIRA & POHREN LTDA - ME  ESSENCIA FARMACIA DE MANIPULACAO    R DR. LUIZ BASTOS DO PRADO, 1610, CENTRO    GRAVATAI    RS  5134881010      206-2 - SOCIEDADE EMPRESARIA LIMITADA   47.71-7-02 - ComÃ©rcio varejista de produtos farmacÃªuticos, com manipulaÃ§Ã£o de fÃ³rmulas 47.72-5-00 - ComÃ©rcio varejista de cosmÃ©ticos, produtos de perfumaria e de higiene pessoal|47.73-3-00 - ComÃ©rcio varejista de artigos mÃ©dicos e ortopÃ©dicos|47.71-7-04 - ComÃ©rcio varejista de medicamentos veterinÃ¡rios 1998-10-09  ATIVA   JOSE ANTONIO POHREN - SÃ³cio-Administrador | SABRINA FRANCISCO PEREIRA - SÃ³cio-Administrador
```

(please disconsider the header formatting, I wasn't able to adjust it here on stackoverflow, it gets all messy if I try to adjust)

Each column is separated by tab. If I open it on Excel it works fine and it looks exactly how it should look, exactly with the same format as the above example.

Im using this code to import it to pandas:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/file.csv",sep='\t')
```

It reads the file however some lines get weird. For instance, I found a line that had that "R DR. LUIZ BASTOS DO PRADO" (that you can see in the line above). Technically it should look exactly the same as above but it is looking like this:

```
CNPJ                                              NaN
Razao social                R DR LUIZ BASTOS DO PRADO
Nome fantasia                                     NaN
Endereco                                          NaN
Cidade                                            NaN
Estado                                            NaN
Telefone                                          NaN
Email                                             NaN
Natureza juridica                                 NaN
Atividade primaria                                NaN
Atividades secundarias                            NaN
Data de fundacao                                  NaN
Situacao cadastral                                NaN
Socios e administradores                          NaN
Capital Social                                    NaN
Name: 291, dtype: object
```

What I noticed is that pandas seems to get confused in the rows that haven't got all columns fulfilled.

I also noticed that this "R DR. LUIZ BASTOS DO PRADO" should be in line 220 and not 291. 291 should be other stuff totally different.

I use read_csv quite often and I have never seen this sort of problem.
Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: try to use `df=pd.read_fwf("/file.csv")` instead...

Comment: Please show the actual line from the file that corresponds to the pandas data you showed.